# C++ only using ^ instead of *?

Tags: .net, pointers, c++-cli, handle

I read that for example

```
MyClass<T> ^ mc = new MyClass<T>();
```

gives a handle of mc.

1. Can I use ^mc the same way I use *mc?

I also read, that using ^mc will create the object in the cli-heap that will automatically cleaned up, so I don't have to use 
`delete mc` then.

Wouldn't that be an argument to only use ^-handles ?

Comment: This is a C++-CLI extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^` pointers are only used in the Microsoft Common Language Runtime modification of of the language. If you use them, you are locking your project to use only the Microsoft compiler. If you're looking for portability, you should use traditional pointers that must be manually deleted or using the new C++11 features.

Answer (score 1):

This is an extension, but you can achieve something similar in standard C++ using:

```
auto mc = std::make_unique<MyClass<T>>();
```

And yes, that's a good reason to use `std::unique_ptr` and/or `std::shared_ptr` whenever you can.

Comment: Your last statement might be misleadingly taken as recommending using pointers where a value would suffice. `shared_ptr`s, when overused, have a lot of potential to tangle the code into a spaghetti mess of unclear ownership.

Comment: thx alot, your answer and the one from coladict together would be the perfect answer ^^

Answer (score 0):

`^` is a managed pointer. It is CLI equivalent of a smart pointer.

> I also read, that using `^mc` will create the object in the cli-heap that will automatically cleaned up, so I don't have to use  `delete mc` then.

Yes, that's true. CLI runtime has a garbage collector. <strike>But CLI is a Windows specific thing so it won't work in other environments.</strike>

Comment: The .NET CoreCLR is now open-sourced (with the promise of Linux and Mac ports, which I haven't checked if they have arrived yet) and there has long existed Mono as an alternative for Linux.

Comment: @coladict I did forgot about Mono, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Also, you can't write `^mc`, it's a syntax error, you can't dereference a handle. You can use the `->` operator on it though.